# issue with php 7.2 and laravel

Tags: php, laravel

iam work with php 7.2 and laravel

```html
$form_data = [
            'sendto' => $response->address,
            'amount' => $transaction->btc_amo,
            'code' => $code,
        ];
```

and this is the .blade.php

```html
    <h3>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.send')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data[amount]}} </span>BTC <br>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.to')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data[sendto]}} </span>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>{{trans('site.blockchain.scan')}}</h2>
    {!!  $form_data[code]  !!}
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3 style="color: red;">** {{trans('site.blockchain.confirmations')}}</h3>
```

i have tried all things and not worked

this error appear

Use of undefined constant sendto - assumed 'sendto' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong, you are missing quotation marks. So it is trying to access the value of the array using a constant as the key, rather than a string. The below should work.

```html
    <h3>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.send')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data['amount']}} </span>BTC <br>
        {{trans('site.blockchain.to')}} <span style="color:red">{{ $form_data['sendto']}} </span>
    </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>{{trans('site.blockchain.scan')}}</h2>
    {!!  $form_data['code']  !!}
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3 style="color: red;">** {{trans('site.blockchain.confirmations')}}</h3>
```